C Double Pointer Reallocation program hangs upon being ran twice in a row
Whenever I try to run this code I've written, it works fine the first time. The second time, the execution hangs up at the end ( it executes everything in the function, but never exits the function ). All the files are in the same folder. These are the files:
main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "matrixTests.h"

int main() {
    
    int8_t a = 0;
    int8_t *p = &a;
    printf("\n%d ", *p);
    printf("\n0x%X ", p);
    printf("\n0x%X ", &a);
    printf("\n0x%X ", &p);
    printf("\n-----------------\n");
    //printSeven();
    //multiDimensionalTest();
    array2Type row_sizes[] = {1,2,3,2,1,7};
    matrixCustomRowLengthsResize(6, row_sizes);
    printf("\n-----------------\n");    

    return 0;
}

matrixTests.h
#ifndef matrixTests
#define matrixTests
#include <stdint.h>

#define array1Type uint16_t 
#define array2Type uint16_t 

void multiDimensionalTest();
void multiDimensionalDemo();
void matrixCustomRowLengths(array2Type nr_rows, array2Type row_lenghts[]);
void matrixCustomRowLengthsResize(array2Type nr_rows, array2Type row_lenghts[]);
void printSeven();


#endif

matrixTests.c (I've included only relevant functions)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "matrixTests.h"

void matrixCustomRowLengths(array2Type nr_rows, array2Type row_lenghts[])
{
    array2Type i = 0;
    array2Type j = 0;
    array2Type arr_size_1 = nr_rows;
    array2Type **arr = (array2Type**)malloc(arr_size_1 * sizeof(array2Type));
    for(i=0;i<arr_size_1;i++)
    {
        printf("Array %d: ", i);
        *(arr+i) = (array2Type*)malloc(row_lenghts[i] * sizeof(array2Type));
        for(j = 0; j < row_lenghts[i]; j++)
        {
            *(*(arr+i) + j) = (array2Type)(i + j);
            printf("Column %d: val = %hu | ", j, *(*(arr+i) + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for( i = arr_size_1-1; i>0; i--)
    {
        free(*(arr+i));
    }
    free(arr);

}

void matrixCustomRowLengthsResize(array2Type nr_rows, array2Type row_lenghts[])
{
        array2Type i = 0;
    array2Type j = 0;
    array2Type arr_size_1 = nr_rows;
    array2Type **arr = (array2Type**)malloc(arr_size_1 * sizeof(array2Type));
    for(i=0;i<arr_size_1;i++)
    {
        printf("Array %d: ", i);
        *(arr+i) = (array2Type*)malloc(row_lenghts[i] * sizeof(array2Type));
        for(j = 0; j < row_lenghts[i]; j++)
        {
            *(*(arr+i) + j) = (array2Type)(i + j);
            printf("Column %d: val = %hu | ", j, *(*(arr+i) + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    printf("\nResize Example\n");
    uint16_t index_resize = nr_rows / 2;
    uint16_t resize_size = 10;
    i = index_resize;
    row_lenghts[i] = (array2Type)resize_size;
    *(arr+i) = (array2Type*)realloc(*(arr+i), row_lenghts[i] * sizeof(array2Type));
    for(i=0;i<arr_size_1;i++)
    {
        printf("Array %d: ", i);
        for(j = 0; j < row_lenghts[i]; j++)
        {
            *(*(arr+i) + j) = (array2Type)(i + j);
            printf("Column %d: val = %hu | ", j, *(*(arr+i) + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for( i = arr_size_1-1; i>0; i--)
    {
        free(*(arr+i));
    }
    free(arr);
}

I run my code with this script:
runThis.bat
gcc -o test test.c matrixTests.c
.\test

The problem only appears when running the matrixCustomRowLengthsResize function.
I tried running it, and expected it to work every time - but it hangs on the second execution.
EDIT: fixed a typo in main.c

array2Type **arr = (array2Type**)malloc(arr_size_1 * sizeof(array2Type)); is wrong for two reasons: 1) You allocate an array of arr_size_1 elements of array2Type values. Not array2Type pointers; And 2) In C you should not cast the result of malloc.

Also remember that for any array or pointer p and index i, the expression *(p + i) is exactly equal to p[i]. The array-index syntax is much easier to read and understand, especially when it comes to arrays of arrays. Don't you think that arr[i][j] is easier to read than *(*(arr+i) + j)? Not to mention that it's less to write as well.

You also have UB because you use the wrong conversion specifiers for printf. printf("\n0x%X ", p); should be printf("\n%p ", (void*)p);

There could be many more issues, but you haven't shown the code that calls matrixCustomRowLengthsResize, so there is no way to know what your are passing or how you are passing the parameters. Please provide A Minimal Complete Reproducible Example.

@DavidC.Rankin in main.c, the line that does the function call should be "matrixCustomRowLengthsResize(6, row_sizes);". It was a typo, I'll make the edit.

It seems the problem has been solved. The problem was this line:
array2Type **arr = (array2Type**)malloc(arr_size_1 * sizeof(array2Type));

It should've been:
array2Type **arr = malloc(arr_size_1 * sizeof(array2Type*));

This would cause a problem later in the program when I would reallocate memory to a given row, since I would cast the malloc to (array2Type*) type, but that memory block was the size of a (array2Type) type instead.
*(arr+i) = (array2Type*)realloc(*(arr+i), row_lenghts[i] * sizeof(array2Type)); //here is where the discrepancy between (array2Type*) and (array2Type) would cause a problem.

For some reason it would result in incorrect behaviour only on a second run. This problem however actually threw a segmentation fault error in an online C compiler, but not on my machine.
The malloc casts were not a problem, but I understand that they are unnecessary.

Avoid sizing miscalculation.  Size to the object, not type: arr = malloc(arr_size_1 * sizeof arr[0]);
